# Simple way to detect continuous lines

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

I have some images of a background, and of steam that I am subtracting to extract just the steam. Unfortunately, because the camera conditions are not perfect the differenced image is always a few pixels off generating sharp lines where features in the background don't match up pixel-by-pixel like so

[image: Sharp lines and some noise]

I'm interested in segmenting out the steam (foreground noise), from the background. I think if I can automatically remove the continuous lines from this image it would be sufficient for my purposes.

Unfortunately it's been almost ten years since my image analysis work and I don't remember what you do to detect continuous lines. What are some simple well preforming algorithms to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I have two methods to suggest:
1. Use the erosion (morphological operator) (you can also use other operators like closing/opening). But i think it will destroy the steam data also...
2. A better solution is to detect the lines using hough transform. Google it and you'll find tons of info about it (if your'e using MATLAB, there is a guide how to do it in their website)

Have fun...

Comment: I don't see how a morphological operator would segment out continuous lines. If they were just vertical or horizontal I could use something, but they're tilted and curved so I need specifically continuous stuff. I've been looking at Hough transform a bit but am not sure I'm understanding how its useful for identifying continuous lines.

Comment: I used the code described here
http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghlines.html
and got good (i did it QnD...).
Any way, hough transform is mainly used to detect lines, the main problem with it that it cannot detect vertical lines so you need to rotate the image to detect these lines.

Comment: Well, i found a more detailed answer, take a look at it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596722/is-there-any-super-fast-algorithm-for-finding-lines-on-picture

Answer (score 2):

One approach is find all contours in your source image and compute the area of each contour. And finally ignore the contours who have area greater than a threshold. You can refer to [Image Processing Place: Contour tracing - Defining connectivity](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/connectivity.html) to know more about contour processing.